# Modify function at runtime (pulling local variable out)

Tags: python, function, bytecode, disassembly

Imagine this simple function creating a modified value of a variable `default`, `modified`:

```
default = 0
def modify():
    modified = default + 1
    print(modified)  # replace with OS call, I can't see the output

modify()  # 1
default  # 0
```

disassembled:

```
import dis
dis.dis(modify)
2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (default)
            3 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
            6 BINARY_ADD
            7 STORE_FAST               0 (modified)
3          10 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (print)
           13 LOAD_FAST                0 (modified)
           16 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
           19 POP_TOP
           20 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
           23 RETURN_VALUE
```

I can't change the function `modify()`, but I know what's in it either directly (I can see the code) or indirectly (disassembly). What I need it is to get a value of the `modified` variable, so I though maybe there is a way how to remove specific parts (`print(modified)`) of the function through `dis` module, but I didn't find anything.

Is there any way how to remove probably everything except `return_value` after `16 CALL_FUNCTION` and replace it with e.g. `return modified`? Or is there any other way how to pull a local variable out without actually executing the last line(s)?

As a possible solution I see 3 ways:

- pulling disassembled codes and creating my own function (or inplace) according to them with removing the code I don't want (everything after `16 ...`)
- modifying the function's *return* value, so that it returns `modified` (that unfortunately calls the OS function)
- manually recreating the function according to the source code

I'd like to avoid the second way, which is probably easier than the first one, but I must avoid the third way, so... is there any way how to solve my problem?

Comment: That isn't a modified version of the variable. It's an entirely new object

Comment: @MosesKoledoye edited (I meant value).

Comment: There is a 4th option: replace the `print()` global. `printed = []; print = lambda *args: printed.extend(args)`, then run `modify()` and, optionaly, `del print` to remove the masking global.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh, I'm blind. So simple and I even went for disassembling! -_- Anyway, if there's a way with disassembling, it might be interesting too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a 4th option: replace the `print()` global:

```
printed = []
print = lambda *args: printed.extend(args)
modify()
del print
modified = printed[0]
```

It is otherwise possible to produce modified bytecode, but this can easily lead to bugs that blow up the interpreter (there is zero protection from invalid bytecode), so be warned.

You can create a new function object with a new code object with updated bytecode; based on the offsets in the dis you showed, I manually created new bytecode that would return the local variable at index 0:

```
>>> altered_bytecode = modify.__code__.co_code[:8] + bytes(
...     [dis.opmap['LOAD_FAST'], 0,   # load local variable 0 onto the stack
...      dis.opmap['RETURN_VALUE']])) # and return it.
>>> dis.dis(altered_bytecode)
          0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (0)
          2 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
          4 BINARY_ADD
          6 STORE_FAST               0 (0)
          8 LOAD_FAST                0 (0)
         10 RETURN_VALUE
```

`RETURN_VALUE` returns the object at the top of the stack; all I did was inject a `LOAD_FAST` opcode to load what `modified` references onto the stack.

You'd have to create a new `code` object, then a new `function` object wrapping the code object, to make this callable:

```
>>> code = type(modify.__code__)
>>> function = type(modify)
>>> ocode = modify.__code__
>>> new_modify = function(
...     code(ocode.co_argcount, ocode.co_kwonlyargcount, ocode.co_nlocals, ocode.co_stacksize,
...          ocode.co_flags, altered_bytecode,
...          ocode.co_consts, ocode.co_names, ocode.co_varnames, ocode.co_filename,
...          'new_modify', ocode.co_firstlineno, ocode.co_lnotab, ocode.co_freevars,
...          ocode.co_cellvars),
...     modify.__globals__, 'new_modify', modify.__defaults__, modify.__closure__)
>>> new_modify()
1
```

This does, obviously, require some understanding of how Python bytecode works in the first place; the `dis` module does contain descriptions of the various codes, and the [`dis.opmap` dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#dis.opmap) lets you map back to byte values.

There are a few modules out there that try to make this easier; take a look at [`byteplay`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/byteplay), the [`bytecode` module of the `pwnypack` project](http://pwnypack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pwnypack/bytecode.html) or several others, if you want to explore this further.

I can also heartily recommend you watch the [*Playing with Python Bytecode* presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mxjv9KqzwjI) given by Scott Sanderson, Joe Jevnik at PyCon 2016, and play with their [`codetransformer` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/codetransformer). Highly entertaining and very informative.

Comment: Hehe, never disappointing Python. There's always a package! I didn't know about the returning of the top item only, this makes things a little bit easier in a case where only a single call is undesired. The bytecode presentation is awesome, I remember watching it on YT.

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr: I was in the audience the first time I saw it. :-D

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr: a previous revision of the post (lost during a grace edit) used just the opcode integers, not `dis.opmap`, which is arguably a little easier to read. :-) Not that I memorise these values however..