# Can a function have an attribute?

Tags: python

I was reading about `__dict__`.
The author of the article wrote this somewhere in his code.

```
def func():
    pass

func.temp = 1
print(func.temp)
```

and I don't understand that.
Can functions have attributes?
I thought it was only possible when writing classes.

i changed the question a little bit.
Thank you for explaining this too....

```
def func():
    x=1
    def inner_func():
        pass
    

print(func.__dict__) #nothing to input

func.temp=1 #what's it ? Attribute?  
func.x=2   #Why it doesn't change the x inside the func
print()

print(func.__dict__) #Why temp and x are within dict
```

Comment: Yes, you can add custom attributes to most Python objects. (Doesn't mean that you necessarily should, though.) Many built-in types are excerpt from this; you can't e.g. add new attributes onto lists or dicts or integers...

Comment: See the [update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67802033/5994041).

Comment: Thanks... I've learned a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python most of the stuff consist of a dictionary (have `__dict__` attribute), therefore it is possible to (mis-)use the language even in this way.

You can modify a function, because:

```
def myfunc(): pass

type(myfunc)
# <class 'function'>
```

a function is still an instance of a `function` class and part of the [`builtins`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html) (injected, because [implemented in C](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bb3e0c240bc60fe08d332ff5955d54197f79751c/Objects/clinic/funcobject.c.h#L27), [also available as symtable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/symtable.html#symtable.Function)) and in that you can find `__dict__` attribute which is storing the properties.

Similarly you can create an empty class or simply use an object that contains a modifiable `__dict__` and by using the "dot" you call in the background:

- [`getattr(object, name[, default])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr)
- [`setattr(object, name, value)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) (for assignment)
- [`delattr(object, name)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#delattr) (for deletion)

which then modify it, thus providing you a way to add/remove/modify attrs approximately like this:

```
object.__dict__["key"]
object.__dict__["key"] = value
del object.__dict__["key"]
```

Edit: As @MegaIng mentioned, it can be used for various purposes, one of which is [`functools.lru_cache()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) to store the cache to remove an expensive function call. ([implementation here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ee7637596d8de25f54261bbeabc602d31e74f482/Lib/functools.py#L637)).

Edit 2: Regarding the changing of a variable within such function - that won't work, because `x` for you in that case is an **attribute** of the function stored in `__dict__` dictionary. It is **not** a variable.

```
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jan 27 2021, 15:41:15) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def myfun(): x=1;print(x)
... 
>>> myfun()
1
>>> 
>>> dir(myfun)
['__annotations__', '__call__', '__class__', '__closure__', '__code__', '__defaults__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__globals__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__kwdefaults__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__name__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__qualname__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
>>> myfun.__globals__
{'__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None, '__loader__': <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>, '__spec__': None, '__annotations__': {}, '__builtins__': <module 'builtins' (built-in)>, 'myfun': <function myfun at 0x7fd5594a7670>}
```

Nothing in these sections, but there's one which contains the value you want to edit and that's `__code__` i.e.:

```
>>> myfun.__code__
<code object myfun at 0x7fd5594afc90, file "<stdin>", line 1>
```

That you can disassemble - it's already been compiled to Python's "virtual" / emulated CPU's (as if you've taken CPU and its instruction set and abstracted it; converted it into a code) bytecode:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(myfun.__code__)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              # here is an assignment of integer `1` into variable `x`
              # via the instruction called `STORE_FAST`
              2 STORE_FAST               0 (x)
              4 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
              6 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             10 POP_TOP
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             14 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
```

Now how to modify that? That's already answered in [a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43185829/5994041) :)

Comment: I would mention that there are good uses for adding an attribute to a function: Most notably a cache.

Answer (score 1):

In Python functions are first class objects, which means that function is an object. You can create function using standard syntax:

```
def foo(x):
  return x+1
```

or using lambdas:

```
bar = lambda x: x+1
```

In both cases `foo` and `bar` are object instances, which may have attributes. Therefore you can create new attributes like you can with regular objects.