# Is there any way to 'overwrite' a function contained within a method of a super-class?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make multiple subclasses, all of which do something slightly different, but the 'core' of the method is the same. To try and solve this, I attempted to write a function in the parent class, then overwrite it in child classes.

Is there a more obvious, simpler, solution that I am completely overlooking?

```py
class SuperClass:
    def __init__(self):
        def func():
            self.val  = 1
            self.val2 = 0
        func()

class SubClass(SuperClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        def func():
            self.val = 2
        func()
```

`print(SubClass().val)`

Returns:

`2`

and

`print(SubClass().val2)`

Returns:

`0`

Is there a way to make the extra `val2` operation not occur?

Comment: What "extra val2 operation"?  Do you mean you don't want `val2` to be initialized at all?  If not, why did you call `super().__init__()`?

Comment: @Samwise for other operations, which I didn't include in this example. Regardless, like others have mentioned, I should probably push that operation to a completely different method.  I forgot I could do that -_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except for disassembling and then creating anew you can't and then it's just the same as if writing the `__init__()` anew in the subclass. The reason why is because the function is created within the local scope of other function thus there's no way to access it until the main function actually executes -- where it then declares the nested function, its body and afterwards, even executes it.

More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43185829/5994041). Not completely the same, but falls into the category or modifying the local scope.

**Edit:** Well, of course, if you don't mind the first execution, then yes, you can call it twice while the second execution, within your subclass' `__init__()` will be then your "overwritten" func. That however isn't overwriting anything, just duplicating. If the point is solely to modify `self.val` it'll work, yet `self.val` will be modified **twice**:

- from the Superclass' `__init__().func()` to `1`
- from the Subclass' `__init__().func()` to `2`

If the actions of Superclass' `__init__()` aren't required, simply skip `super().__init__()` and let only your subclass' func execute, then it'll be overwritten, however without any superclass' behavior defined in `__init__()` present.

**Edit2:** Instead of introducing nested functions use a proper class' method:

```
class Superclass:
    def helper(self):
        self.val = 1
    def __init__(self):
        self.helper()

class Subclass(Superclass):
    def helper(self):
        self.val = 2

print(Superclass().val)
print(Subclass().val)
```

Comment: I updated the question with new information. Yeah, I can't let both operations happen. What if I only call it in the subclass, and just not define it at all if I want it to be the same as the base?

Comment: @AmmarAldabbagh The thing is you are calling `func()` within the init itself, therefore you can't ***modify*** anything from outside after such code. That's why it's better to have the function either as a method or a completely separate (out of class' body) function. *Then* you can overwrite pretty much anything.

Comment: What I meant was only call `func()` in the subclass but not the base class. Turns out `super()` doesn't send functions through, because it raised "`name 'func' is not defined`."

Comment: @AmmarAldabbagh There's no reason for a function's *local* scope to be propagated anywhere. It's whole reason is to be executed when the function is called and to die after the code block of the function ends. That's why `name 'func' is not defined`. Don't create nested functions and you won't have such problems. Or, see the edits above: 1) edit the bytecode or ignore the superclass' `__init__()` and rewrite it in subclass / don't call `super()` 2) have it called twice 3) create a class' method which is patchable the way you want. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since `func` is the thing you want to be modifiable, it should live at class level and it should be the thing overridden. The way you've written it, the class does a thing, then completely throws it away for another thing. This is not only wasteful of processing speed, its hard to maintain. Intermediate values from a superclass "func" may still stick around in the subclasses.

Make `func` the thing to override

```
class SuperClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.func()

    def func(self):
        self.val = 1
        
class SubClass(SuperClass):

    def func(self):
        self.val = 2

print(SubClass().val)
```